# Getting jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException, when HTTP response is 204 (no content)

Tags: java, rest, api, automation, jersey-client

I am using jersey-client 1.8, for my REST Automation
I am getting the following exception whenever I am getting the HTTP response 204 (no content): 
**Exception:**

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: DELETE https://MYURL returned a response status of 204 No Content

    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:528)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506).
```

**My Code to get the response**

```
case DELETE:
        {
            HEADER_AUTH = getAuthHeader(uname,pwd);
            wResource = client.resource(URI);
            response = wResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                    header("Authorization", HEADER_AUTH).
                    type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                    delete(ClientResponse.class, payload);
            response_string = response.getEntity(String.class);
            status = response.getStatus();
            apiResponseString = new HashMap<>();
            apiResponseString.put("response", response_string);
            apiResponseString.put("status", ""+status);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is nothing to read. [HTTP 204](https://httpstatuses.com/204) is meaning "NO CONTENT".

Execute that call in another tool (curl, postman..) to see does content exists.